# Stop hover and click on element with not specific class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable the hover (and click) on elements which do not have a specific class name attribute:

```
<svg>
   <path class="myClass"></path>
   <path class="myClass active"></path>
</svg>
```

***Basically if path has not attribute className "active" don't hover or click***

Tried:

```
    if (!$("path").hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    };
```

But I believe I should use `.attr("class"..)` since it is a `svg path`

Comment: Use `$("path.active").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')`

Comment: with that you are saying to stop it when it has .active, i want the opposite, also i believe it has to be done by .attr

Comment: Instead of removing the event handler, why dont you set the event handler only on the elements having class active?

Comment: @void because the code it is much more complex, at first i want to hover and click regardless of the .active class, then the whole interaction logic changes and I need what in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo uses the `.attr()` function. with this you will have to loop through each desired element and loop its class list (if exist) and see if it contains the `.active` class if not then unbind the events of that element.

```js
$('p').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
})

$('p').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'black');
})


$('p').each(function(indx, elem) {
    var activeNotFound = 1;
    var classes = [];
    if ($(elem).attr('class') !== undefined) { // check if elem has attribute class
     classes = $(elem).attr('class').split(" "); // split into array the attribute class
        $.each(classes, function(ndx, classname) { // loop each class to check if active exist
            if (classname === 'active') {
                activeNotFound = 0;
            }
          // removed the else part.
        });
    }
    
    if (activeNotFound) { // if no active class found unbind events
        $(elem).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    }
})
```

```css
div p {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

p.active {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Note: I used a different element for this demo. Just change it to the needed elements and also update the script</h4>
<div>
    <p class="myClass"></p>
    <p class="myClass active"></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add event handler only to element has `.active` class. But if you can't do it, use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to select element hasn't `.active` class.

```
$("path:not(.active)").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
```

Comment: yes ok but how about targetting a class by using `.attr`?

Comment: @rob.m `.attr("class")` return all content of class attribute. You should split result by space to find every class name.

Comment: exactly, i need to target a specific class (.active) within the whole class attribute

Comment: @rob.m Glad to help. Also you can mark answer to finishing this discussion :)

Comment: i would like to, yet it is not answering 100% since I asked with the attribute while you answered with a class targhetting. It maybe confusing for other users landing on here